# Modify row height in ApexChart

Tags: apexcharts

please see this code:

```
let options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'rangeBar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: '30%'
        }
    },
    grid: {
        show: true,
        xaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            }
        },
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: [
            "lunes",
            "martes",
            "mi\u00E9rcoles",
            "jueves",
            "viernes",
            "s\u00E1bado",
            "domingo"
        ],
        labels: {
            maxHeight: 20,
            rotate: 90
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 24
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: [
              {
                  "x": "lunes",
                  "y": [
                      15,
                      18
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "x": "martes",
                  "y": [
                      15,
                      18
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "x": "mi\u00E9rcoles",
                  "y": [
                      15,
                      18
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "x": "jueves",
                  "y": [
                      15,
                      18
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "x": "viernes",
                  "y": [
                      15,
                      18
                  ]
              }
          ]
        }
    ]
};

chartObj = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chartObj.render();
```

It is in this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/desytec/cq2xog7f/34/

Is it possible to make the row height of the chart smaller? In the default, range bars appear too much separated one to each other.

I tried by modifying some CSS styles but I could not find which one can make it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. What do you mean row height? You may change [the height](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/height/) of the whole chart, and since it will always have seven categories vertically, each one will get smaller. But the bars are separated (if you mean vertically separated) because of your option [`barHeight: '30%'`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/#barHeight).